# What is a proper way to reverse the order of nested java Maps

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-9

I'm trying to reverse the order of a nested Map.

As there is no built-in function in Map to reverse the order and I'm out of time. I tried several available methods of reversing the order posted by devs but nothing worked and also I didn't see any error. I don't know what's wrong with the code probably because I've not used Map that much and I'm relatively new to java.

Here is the structure of the map
`Map<String, HashMap<String, Object>> playersDataMap = new HashMap<> ();`

And these are a couple of methods I copied from a website but none of them worked. It always returns me the with the same order.

```
    public static <K extends Comparable, V> Map<K,V> sortByKeys(Map<K,V> map)
    {
        Map<K, V> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<K>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(K a, K b) {
                return b.compareTo(a);
            }
        });

        treeMap.putAll(map);

        return treeMap;
    }

    public static <K, V> Map<K,V> sortByTreeMap(Map<K,V> unsortedMap)
    {
        // construct a TreeMap from given Map and return a reverse order
        // view of the mappings contained in this map
        return new TreeMap<>(unsortedMap).descendingMap();
    }
```

I also tried changing the HashMap to LinkedHashMap but no success, same results.

Please let me know what is wrong with the code. I'm really out of time otherwise I would have read the docs of Maps before posting or even implementation. Your help will be greatly appreciated. thanks

Here is the example of what I'm trying to implement

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, Object>> playersDataMap = new LinkedHashMap<> ();
for (int i = 1; i < 40; i++)
{
    HashMap<String, Object> playerMap = new HashMap<> ();
    playerMap.put ("name", "abc"+i);
    playerMap.put ("pointsScored", i * 10);
    playersDataMap.put ("x"+i, playerMap);
}


Map<String, HashMap<String, Object>> inversedPlayerDataMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
inversedPlayerDataMap = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
inversedPlayerDataMap.putAll(playersDataMap);

for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, Object>> player : inversedPlayerDataMap.entrySet ())
{
    System.out.printf ("Debug: player key: %s playerValueScore: %s \n", player.getKey (), player.getValue ().get("pointsScored"));
}
```

Results: "Debug: player key: x9 pointsScored: 90" "Debug: player key: x390 pointsScored: 390" "Debug: player key: x30 pointsScored: 30" ...

Expected output: "Debug: player key: x390 pointsScored: 390" "Debug: player key: x380 pointsScored: 380" ...

Comment: If you tested the above 2 methods, then it's likely that your expectations are questionable. Please add test data and expected output

Comment: Also i'm creating a new reference variable of the sorted map this way

Map<String, HashMap<String, Object>> inversedPlayerDataMap = sortByKeys (playersDataMap);

I hope there is no issue in it

Comment: Thanks @ernest_k, as i already said i'm relatively new to java so it is possible that I'm something really weird above.
Do you know any quicker way to sort this out? Before going with the test data...

Comment: @ernest_k I've updated the question to explain what I'm trying to produce. Please take a look. thanks!

Comment: @TomStroemer can you please post your answer, how can I convert my implementation to TreeMap.

The end results, I just need a Map type data because firebase realtime database not except any other type. thanks

Comment: HashMaps are unordered. There is no order to reverse.

Comment: @user207421 can you please post your answer fixing the issue.
Please take a look at what I'm trying to implement at the end of questions.

Comment: Your logic to reverse the map is fine but while printing it you  are not using the reversed map but the original map. Check the "playersDataMap.entrySet ()" it should be "inversedPlayerDataMap.entrySet ()"

Comment: @ArvindKumar this was just for an example. It's not the actual code.
Although, I've updated it. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @waleed By doing so don't you have the expected result as you have mentioned in the description. I can see the exact result.

Comment: ..and where is the method sortByKeys()

Comment: @Voodoo it’s in the first code snippet

Comment: @Holger: I definitely need a new glasses .

Comment: @Holger can you please post your answer with this comparator implementation. 
Please implement it in the last code example snipper. It will be much helpful because I never used it before.

Comment: @Holger you are right, it never reproduces the problem let me update the last snippet

Comment: @Holger i've updated the question please take a look at the last example snippet now

Comment: You have `String` keys and the natural order of strings is their lexicographic order. In other words, `"x9" > "x390"`. You would need something like `Comparator.comparingInt((String s) -> Integer.parse(s.substring(1))).reversed()` to sort descending by the numerical value. However, when the keys have a more complex pattern, i.e. a mixture of words and numbers, a comparator providing your desired order is not trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the above answers worked but to some extent. They didn't work on a mixed string.

So what I did is replaced the HashMap to linkedHashMap. Then I added the keySet of that Map to newly created List of strings and reversed it using Collections.reverse then iterated through that list and added the reserved order into a new Map.

Here is the code of my invert function.

**Important**, the argument i passed as a playersDataMap is a linkedHashMap. For further explanation on LinkedHashMap please go to the following link https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/linkedhashmap-in-java/. thanks!

```
public static Map<String, HashMap<String, Object>> invertMapUsingList (Map<String, HashMap<String, Object>> playersDataMap)
{
        Map<String, HashMap<String, Object>> inversedPlayerDataMap = new LinkedHashMap<> ();
        List<String> reverseOrderedKeys = new ArrayList<String>(playersDataMap.keySet());
        Collections.reverse(reverseOrderedKeys);
        for (String key : reverseOrderedKeys)
        {
            inversedPlayerDataMap.put (key, playersDataMap.get(key));
        }

        return inversedPlayerDataMap;
}
```

Comment: You should have used a `TreeMap` and a `Comparator` as everybody told you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you please elaborate what's wrong with this solution? have you read all the comments above to know why i finally ended up with this solution.

Comment: Also i tried using Comparator but no success. It didn't work when i had strings that was not comparable. e.g. ("asdfhouoweiu0sdf", jasdfjd-f4sdjljfasfj, "dsajfkjh-sadj3df")

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is reverse your current map, then this will do it.

Here is the test Map

```
for (int i = 10; i < 300; i += 10) {

    playerMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    playerMap.put("name", "person" + (i / 10));
    playerMap.put("pointsScored", i);

    playersDataMap.put("x" + i, playerMap);

}
```

Here is the comparator.  Note that this depends on `x` being the same for keys in the enclosing map.

```
Comparator<String> comp = Comparator
        .comparing(String::length)
        .thenComparing(String::compareTo)
        .reversed();
```

And the sorting

```
inversedPlayerDataMap = new TreeMap<>(comp);
inversedPlayerDataMap.putAll(playersDataMap);


for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, Object>> player : inversedPlayerDataMap
                .entrySet()) {
    System.out.printf(
                    "Debug: player key: %s playerValueScore: %s \n",
                    player.getKey(),
                    player.getValue().get("pointsScored"));
    }
}
```

Prints

```
...
...
...
Debug: player key: x130 playerValueScore: 130 
Debug: player key: x120 playerValueScore: 120 
Debug: player key: x110 playerValueScore: 110 
Debug: player key: x100 playerValueScore: 100 
Debug: player key: x90 playerValueScore: 90 
Debug: player key: x80 playerValueScore: 80 
...
...
...
```

Not certain why you are using a Map of Maps, though.  Is the key to the outerMap any importance (Like a team designator perhaps?)

Comment: Yes, it is important. it's an id of the player.

Comment: @Holger can you please elaborate.

Comment: I'm getting exception of "can't resove Entry". Which class is this?

Comment: Ignore my last answer.  @Holger is correct (per usual).  See my updated answer.

Comment: To whomever, thanks for the somewhat undeserving upvote.

Comment: i've tried on 39 keys and didn't get the expected results.
I've updated my question please take a look at the last example snippet code. Thanks!

Comment: it does not work when you have a mixed pattern of strings.
I started it with -4 and it failed to produce reversed order

Comment: do you know how can I fix? I think something is related to the comparator.

Comment: You can sort on entire string in reversed order but the numbers will not be in order.  Or you can sort on the number part.  You need to decide how you want them sorted.

Comment: thanks, @WJS. Actually, the above code snippet is just for testing or elaborating the requirement. The actually userId is a mixed string and I think It's kind of impossible to use comparator on that.
I found another solution of reversing the order by using arraList and keyset of data map.
I'll post it after the final testing.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be or more help.

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to help and thanks for your time.
I've posted my answer. You can check it out if you want to know how I solved the issue.
thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Original answer]

Your approach of using a `Map` can be problematic. You should create a new type and use a `List` of the new type.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class MyType {
    String playerKey;
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public MyType(String id, Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.playerKey = id;
        this.map = map;
    }

    public String getPlayerKey() {
        return playerKey;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "playerKey=" + playerKey + ", pointsScored=" + map.get("pointsScored");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyType> playersData = new ArrayList<MyType>();
        playersData.add(new MyType("x1", Map.of("name", "john", "pointsScored", 50)));
        playersData.add(new MyType("x11", Map.of("name", "harry", "pointsScored", 55)));
        playersData.add(new MyType("x2", Map.of("name", "tina", "pointsScored", 60)));
        playersData.add(new MyType("y1", Map.of("name", "richard", "pointsScored", 60)));
        playersData.add(new MyType("y12", Map.of("name", "kim", "pointsScored", 45)));
        playersData.add(new MyType("y3", Map.of("name", "karen", "pointsScored", 65)));
        System.out.println("Orinally:");
        playersData.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        playersData.sort(new Comparator<MyType>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(MyType t1, MyType t2) {
                String s1 = t1.getPlayerKey();
                String s2 = t2.getPlayerKey();

                int compVal;
                int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
                String sn1 = "", sn2 = "";

                // Pattern to find a sequence of digits
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
                Matcher matcher;

                matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    // Number from first string
                    sn1 = matcher.group();
                    n1 = Integer.valueOf(sn1);
                }

                matcher = pattern.matcher(s2);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    // Number from first string
                    sn2 = matcher.group();
                    n2 = Integer.valueOf(sn2);
                }

                // Compare the string part
                compVal = s2.substring(0, s2.indexOf(sn2)).compareTo(s1.substring(0, s1.indexOf(sn1)));

                // If string parts are same, compare the number parts
                if (compVal == 0 && n1 != 0 && n2 != 0) {
                    compVal = Integer.compare(n2, n1);
                }
                return compVal;
            }
        });

        System.out.println("\nSorted in reversed order of playerKey:");
        playersData.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

## [Update]

You can use `Map` in the following way:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * 
 * Comparator to compare alphanumeric words in the form of LETTERS+DIGITs e.g.
 * A1, ABC123 etc.
 *
 */
class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

        int compVal;
        int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
        String sn1 = "", sn2 = "";

        // Pattern to find a sequence of digits
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher matcher;

        matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            // Number from first string
            sn1 = matcher.group();
            n1 = Integer.valueOf(sn1);
        }

        matcher = pattern.matcher(s2);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            // Number from first string
            sn2 = matcher.group();
            n2 = Integer.valueOf(sn2);
        }

        // Compare the string part
        compVal = s2.substring(0, s2.indexOf(sn2)).compareTo(s1.substring(0, s1.indexOf(sn1)));

        // If string parts are same, compare the number parts
        if (compVal == 0 && n1 != 0 && n2 != 0) {
            compVal = Integer.compare(n2, n1);
        }
        return compVal;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, HashMap<String, Object>> playersDataMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            HashMap<String, Object> playerMap = new HashMap<>();
            playerMap.put("name", "abc" + i);
            playerMap.put("pointsScored", i * 10);
            playersDataMap.put("x" + i, playerMap);
        }

        Map<String, HashMap<String, Object>> inversedPlayerDataMap = new TreeMap<>(new MyComparator());
        inversedPlayerDataMap.putAll(playersDataMap);
        for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, Object>> entry : inversedPlayerDataMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out
                    .println("playerKey=" + entry.getKey() + ", pointsScored=" + entry.getValue().get("pointsScored"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
playerKey=x10, pointsScored=100
playerKey=x9, pointsScored=90
playerKey=x8, pointsScored=80
playerKey=x7, pointsScored=70
playerKey=x6, pointsScored=60
playerKey=x5, pointsScored=50
playerKey=x4, pointsScored=40
playerKey=x3, pointsScored=30
playerKey=x2, pointsScored=20
playerKey=x1, pointsScored=10
```

Comment: Can you please update the last example according to your implementation. Because there are some limits that's why the main playersDataMap is

Map<String, HashMap<String, Object>> playersDataMap = new HashMap<> ();

Comment: I'll let you know when i try it.
Right now, I'm trying some other approaches

Comment: @waleed  - I've updated my answer to use `Map<String, HashMap<String, Object>>`. I hope, it fulfils your requirement.

Comment: Thank you @Arvind.
I've used the above answer and it's working as intended. 
But thanks again for your contribution.

Comment: @waleed - Just a question, in the reversed order, do you want `x10` or `x2` to appear first? If you want `x10` to appear before `x2` in your reversed order, this answer fulfils this requirement.

Comment: thank you so much for your time and i'm really sorry i couldn't try it. 

But i doubt it will work on a mixed sort of string keys as you're using HashMap for your main playersDataMap and Hashmap doesn't maintain any order. Probably it will work at some extent but i doubt when you have thousands of players in that map. But i'm not saying absolutely as i've not tried it out.

Anyway, I've posted my answer. You can check it out if you want to know how I solved the issue.

But thanks again for your time i really appreciate it.

Comment: @waleed - You are most welcome. If you remember (or if you check my edits), I had given you the first solution with `Collections.reverse()` but you had said that it would not work. Anyway, I wish you success!

Comment: Thanks you for your kind words, I've upvoted it because of your time ...

Btw for information, Collection.reverse() never works if you don't a have Map in order. In this question context it means if you don't use the LinkedHashMap